# Can I assign a time value for an entire dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I would like to implement the following solution:

I have datasets that are generated every 5 minutes, those have several colums and rows, where the row are the variables and the metrics in the rows.

The issue is that I would like to load those entire datasets and assign them the time they have been loaded for all of the variables in the given time for the same exact metric value, ¿Does it make any sense?.

A
dding a column with the time as a metric for eacehone of the variables, but I would like to know if I could do it globally as a dataframe in R, and everytime I'm accessing to this dataframe, keep it in an inside variable as it would apply to each element of the dataframe (the time of the extraction).

Thank you.

EDIT: Imagine the following table for T1, I load it in one dataframe call it df1.

```
PlaneID  FlightTime  Passengers  Cost
1         123             5       6
2          34             4       2
3          93             3       1
```

Now the very next day I recieve a new data report, on the time T2 and save it on a df2:

```
PlaneID  FlightTime  Passengers  Cost
1          33             10      16
2          134            2       1
3          393            3       6
```

Now, what I'd like to do (besides being on different dataframes) would be for example to analyze the number of passangers for each plane during T1 and T2, and creating a time series out of it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: some sample data would be incredibly helpful. What does your data look like? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: why don't you just add a column to your received `data.frame` with a timestamp ? `df$timestamp <- timestamp()`

Comment: Hey guys I edited my answer, maybe it helps now. Thanks both